# Microsoft Outlook grouping e-mails

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2011

I have MS Outlook 2011 for Mac and if the subject for the e-mails are the same, it will group them together in the same thread which makes it very hard to keep track on the subjects.

Is there a way to disable threading or fix it so they don't group up based on e-mail subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have Conversation View turned on...

When it is turned on, it will group all emails of the same subject, regardless of who has sent them or when they were sent. It will also show the emails you have sent yourself within the conversation.

http://answers.uchicago.edu/page.php?id=27113

The above article will show you how to turn it off and arrange by date, regardless of the subject